# Unchecking "rebuild theme cache" caused site to break

Tags: 7

I'm new to Drupal and I've unchecked the "rebuild theme cache" option on my Drupal 7 site, now the site only shows a blank white page when loading (no html returned when I view the source on Firefox). After turning on error reporting on index.php I get this error:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class InsertQuery in /var/webroot/database/query.inc on line 727`

Does anybody know how to undo this? I'm assuming it's some row I need to modify in the Drupal database.